# How to add conditional tooltip using primeng?

Tags: primeng

I am trying to add a conditional tooltip over a button. Using primeng tooltip component:

```
<div pTooltip="Please upload" style="display:inline-block;" tooltipPosition="top" 
   tooltipDisabled = "flag">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check" 
     aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

It is not working.

However, tooltip without "tooltipDisabled" is working fine.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: @Kukeltje sure, will keep that in mind.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `[tooltipDisabled]="flag"` instead

Answer (score 0):

tooltipDisabled is looking for a boolean.
You are giving it a string (and not the `flag` attribute of your component as I would expect seeing the code).

Use `[tooltipDisabled]="flag"` instead.

Comment: Please educate others by telling them to **not** use the PrimeFaces tag for PrimeNG questions

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but maybe help others like helped to me. The listed solutions did not solve my problem but give me an idea: Only when i put `[pTooltip]="variableWithMyText"` with brackets and bind into a local variable with text content and combined with `[tooltipDisabled]="flag"`, my code worked perfectly.

HTML (Condensed to minimum attributes for explanation):

```
<div [pTooltip]="tooltipText" [tooltipDisabled]="hideTooltip"></div>
```

Typescriptp file (Condensed to minimum attributes for explanation):

```
hideTooltip: boolean;
tooltipText = 'This text will showed on Tooltip';

if(conditionToShowTooltip){
    this.hideTooltip = true;
} else {
    this.hideTooltip = false;
}
```